# No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag

Tags: git, composer-php

I created a private Git repository with a Composer package in it.
My `composer.json` is in the root of the repo:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/nameofpackage",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "blaaa",
    "license": "All rights reserved.",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "keywords": ["a", "b", "c"] 
}
```

But if I want to run any Composer command (with `-v`), I get:

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of [url], could not load a package from it.

Exception trace:
 () at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:265
 Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->initialize() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:179
 Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:104
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/ShowCommand.php:300
 Composer\Command\ShowCommand->getPackage() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/ShowCommand.php:129
 Composer\Command\ShowCommand->execute() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:167
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:98
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://D:/wamp/www/mosaicgenerator/skeletonmosaic/api/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at D:\wamp\www\mosaicgenerator\skeletonmosaic\api\composer.phar:25
```

I can definitely access the Git repo, it's fine. It only has master branch (no branch).

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't add a "version" key to the `composer.json`, because every commit that has the file would be marked as being version 0.0.1 now. This will fail, and might be the reason for your problem. Versions will be marked by using tags in the repository.

Comment: I'm only using the version key to follow changes, it's not used by anything I think. It's only there for my eyes.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version "The version of the package. In most cases this is not required and should be omitted (see below)." You are supposed to tag versions in your repository. If you are in need to quickly see which version you are working on: `git describe` will tell you more exactly that this version key: `0.0.1-10-g156ad78` means you are on version 0.0.1, with 10 more commits after the tag, and the current commit is a Git repo ("g") with ID 156ad78.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as I found out, there were an SSL certificate problem on the server, so the git and composer couldn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a public package which is meant for everyone to use. You will have to register it at [Packagist](https://packagist.org) so that your local Composer can find it.

If this is a private package which is meant only for you or your team. Then use the private repositories solution of Composer in your local `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

See the [Composer Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) for more information.